# Getting issue when implementing angular grid in mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I have one MVC project where previously i used kendo controller all the things are fine there.

Now when i added angularjs ui grid in my new and used kendo datepicker so angular js was not working because of i added those angular.js script in _layout.cshtml page just after kendo.all.min.js. but did not find angularjs worked. so i removed the script from there and added those script in newly created view so angular grid is working now but the new issue i got that is Jquery function not defined for kendo datepicker. i know this issue becasue jquery.min.js it is used now in two places first in layout.cshtml and second in new view. if i remove this jquery.min.js script from new view gettting issue like angularjs injecterr. if i am using this view my kendo datepicker is not working.

If anyone who have idea to set all the angularjs script in _layout.cshtml only then it would be good.

Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more layout used in application name as MyLayout.cshtml i added those script there and removed the same from Layout.cshtml page and now angular and kendo controls both are working fine without any issue.